# how to show a iframe in iphone application

Tags: iphone, asp.net

how to show Iframe on iphone application 
i want to simply make sql base php page which shows the database record after login

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use  WebView to show an html page in iPhone application. That page can contain iframe and other html elements.

Comment: and if user use this application can he able to known that its not thee part of application??

Comment: No, WebView is part of applicaion and does not invoke external browser.  If your app handles exceptions well (E.g .the case when server is not reachable) this would be transparent to user.

Comment: and how to handle this server is not reachable

Comment: You will have to intercept the request and handle error conditions. Example of intercept : http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/04/07/changing-the-headers-for-uiwebkit-http-requests/